# For file loop in a for file loop batch file

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I have a program to ping computers, check there registry, and tell me the results.
I am now trying to script it so that I don't have to know the ip address just the host name of the computer.
I found a script to give me the ip off of a hostname

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=[]" %%a in ('ping -4 %%a  ^| find "Pinging"') do set ip=%%c >nul
```

I have tried to simply insert this into a biger loop that uses a file to give it the host names.

```
for /f %%A in (%1) do (
    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=[]" %%a in ('ping -4 %%a  ^| find "Pinging"') do (
        set host=%%a
        set ip=%%c
        echo "."
        echo %ip% %host%
        pause
        ) >>%2
    )
```

I have also tried it like this,

```
for /f %%a in (%1) do (
    set /p hostname=%%a
    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=[]" %%b in ('ping -4 %%a  ^| find "Pinging"') do set ip=%%c >nul
    echo %ipaddress% %hostname% 
)
```

Please any help on this would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: you need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Comment: why do not simply `echo %%c %%a` instead of setting variables?

Comment: In your last script, what do you expect `set /p %%a=hostname` to do?

Comment: I tried both and it still dos nothing, also the %%a=hostname is a typo it shuld be hostname=%%a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFTER MUTCH HEAD BANGING

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f %%A in (%1) do (
    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=[]" %%a in ('ping /4 /n 1 %%A ^| findstr "Pinging"') do echo "%%A %%b"
)
```